Why is type {} (non-nullish values) assignable to subtypes like { [key: string]: string }?
Type {} refers to non-nullish values; it does not refer to objects with no properties.
But I noticed this behaviour:
const x: {} = 0; // okay, since 0 is a non-nullish value
const y: { [key: string]: string } = 0; // error, since 0 is not a { [key: string]: string }
const z: { [key: string]: string } = x; // okay, unexpected

I expected TypeScript to throw an error for the z assignment, like it does for the y assignment. Yet it type checks. Is it a bug?

It's not a bug. The type of x is the anonymous empty object type {}, which gets an implicit index signature. Since {} has no known properties, none of them conflict with {[key: string]: string}, and thus the assignment is allowed.  This is unsafe but it's intentional. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz But {} does not refer to the empty object type according to this link. So it's not an object literal type. So the implicit index signature should not apply, should it?

It's still called the "empty object type". Parse it like "empty (object type)", not "(empty object) type".  It doesn't refer only to empty objects.  Regardless, I don't see how you conclude "it's not an object literal type", and then how you can go on to conclude that an "index signature should not apply". Those statements are either correct-but-unrelated or incorrect, depending on what you're trying to say. Can you articulate more clearly what the potential objection is here? It seems like non sequiturs to me.

@jcalz My current understanding is that implicit index signatures only apply to object literal types according to the link you provided. So if {} is not an object literal type, it does not apply to it. And the link I provided explicitly says that {} does not refer to the empty object but to all objects except undefined and null, so {} is not an object literal type otherwise it would only refer to the empty object. I might be wrong.

All documentation I can find uses "object literal type" to mean "the type TS ends up giving to an object literal" but not "a type that prohibits extra properties". It is only distinguished from interfaces.  See the TS design notes in ms/TS#7059. So {} is indeed an "object literal type" and it gets an implicit index signature. Only interfaces don't get implicit index signatures. So, can I proceed now, or are you still in some sort of disagreement that prevents direct progress?

@jcalz Alright. I think on the contrary having a technical discussion helps progress because it fosters more in-depth knowledge. But yes please proceed.

This is working as intended, although it does demonstrate that assignability is not transitive. That is, there are types A, B, and C such that A extends B and B extends C but not A extends C. Transitivity of assignability is often true, but because TypeScript's type system is not fully sound, there are places where transitivity fails.  You've found one of them: number extends {} is true, and {} extends {[key: string]: string} is true, but number extends {[key: string]: string} is false.  For other examples and discussions, see microsoft/TypeScript#42479 and microsoft/TypeScript#47331.

So
const x: {} = 0;

is allowed because {} has no known properties and therefore none of 0's apparent members conflict with it.
And
const y: { [key: string]: string } = 0; // error

is disallowed because not every apparent member of 0 is assignable to string.  For example, the toFixed member has type (fractionDigits?: number | undefined) => string, which is not a string.  So it fails to match the index signature.
But why is
const z: { [key: string]: string } = x; // okay

allowed?

Well, the anonymous empty object type {} is not an interface, and therefore it can get an implicit index signature. Interfaces do not get implicit index signatures, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#15300, and discussed in the design notes in microsoft/TypeScript#7059; interfaces are mentioned in opposition to object literal types, and from context, we can conclude that non-interface object types are object literal types.  (Presumably, such types have syntax like an object literal, with a surrounding {⋯}, and object literal values are given such types as well.)
Anyway, from the handbook description of implicit index signatures:

An object literal type is assignable to a type with an index signature if all known properties in the object literal are assignable to that index signature.

Since x is of type {}, then {} is compared to { [key: string]: string }.  The type {} has no known properties, so it is trivially assignable to the string index signature. And therefore the implicit index signature matches and the assignment succeeds:
const z: { [key: string]: string } = x; // okay


Again, there's an unsoundness here. Merely because an object type isn't known to conflict with an index signature, it doesn't mean there is no conflict. Missing properties are not necessarily undefined. This might be what you are getting at by saying that a variable of type {} isn't necessarily an empty object. It can have all kinds of properties, and these properties might conflict with any given index signature.  Yes, this is unsafe. But these assignments are so convenient that it would be really annoying to use the "safe" version that continually errors, which is indeed why implicit index signatures were introduced in the first place, to stop annoying developers with safety rules that hampered productivity.
Not everyone agrees with such decisions, but we can at least be certain that, for the examples shown here, TypeScript is behaving exactly as intended. It's not a bug.

Thanks a lot, I get it now! type T1 = {} extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false; is true because of implicit index signature since it makes it equivalent to type T1 = { [key: string]: string } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false;. Without implicit index signature, it would be equivalent to type T1 = { [key: string | number | symbol]: any } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false; and so would be false. And this is not specific to {}: type T2 = { x: string } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false; is true for the same reason!

But { [key: string | number | symbol]: any } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false is true because of any, and I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. Without an implicit index signature it would be equivalent to interface Foo {} and then Foo extends {[k: string]: string} ? true : false which is indeed false.  Indeed it is not specific to {}, but works for any non-interface object type.

Oh yes, I forgot that any can be assigned to anything. So I meant never: without implicit index signature, T1 would be equivalent to { [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false which  is false, and T2 would be equivalent to { x: string; [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown } extends { [key: string]: string } ? true : false which is false as well. What I mean is that without implicit index signature, object literal types accept any properties.

I don't think it's a bug, since when you say:
const z: { [key: string]: string } = x;

The compiler does not check what the content of x is but checks what its type is and its type can indeed match.
Unlike this line:
const y: { [key: string]: string } = 0;

that the compiler knows to recognize immediately that the types do not match.
